# Error Code :XamlC error XFC0000 : Cannot resolve type "MediaElement"

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I just updated to Xamarin Forms 5 and I cannot seem to fix this error, my app was completely fine before this and had no errors and now I updated I get this error and all of my dependencies have a yellow warning symbol on them, any help would be appreciated thanks.[This image is a screenshot of the error along with my page that it is saying the error is on and my dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xg42p.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please avoid including screenshots of code or error messages. You should include the error message itself. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to better formulate your question.

Answer (score 0):

`MediaElement` has been moved to [Xamarin Community Toolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit/) package ([soruce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/5.0/5.0.0#c-ui-expander-and-mediaelement-moved)). Under the xaml namespace:

```
xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
<xct:MediaElement ...
```

#### Official documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/mediaelement

#### Official repo

https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit

Comment: This does not fix the problem.

Comment: @LevesqueXylia could you specify exactly what is the error which remains ?

Comment: It's a 4-year old bug and still open here, with a work-around: https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/1311

Comment: @ThanhNguyen thanks for mentioning the girhub issue, just to clarify the OP was not using MediaElement from xct package as you can see in the screenshot attached, also that error does neither cause the build to fail nor affect the final output (check issue you linked) so i believe the real issue of the OP in this question was about MediaElement moving to xct package and not the xamlc error which I think it is a VS/tooling issue.